# Conflict between drawing both textures and lines with colors in GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

My aim is to draw textures and to draw a colored line over the top in a GlKViewController.  Both parts work individually, but when I combine the two into the same draw function I lose the textures - they're colored in with the same color as the line.

In my draw method-

First, the code for my textured triangles:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;


    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nLiveSquares*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Followed by the code for my lines:

```
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = NO;
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _lineBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(LinePoint),(const GLvoid *) offsetof(LinePoint, Position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(LinePoint),(const GLvoid *) offsetof(LinePoint, Color));

// Set the line width
glLineWidth(50.0);

// Render the line

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);
```

The problem seems to arise with using the GLKVertexAttribColor.  As soon as I apply the color attribute to the lines the textures are all also colored in the same color as the lines.

Edit:  Part of the problem seems to be resolved using

```
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
```

after the glDrawArrays on the last line above.

My textures are no longer colored the same color as the line, but now they're displayed as white rectangles, which is not really an improvement.

Also, if I comment out the 'self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES' and 'self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = NO' then my textures are properly displayed, but my line becomes black (when it should be green).

Edit II:  I think what I'm really looking for is a way to switch off textures for one block (drawing lines) and then switch them back on again for drawing the triangles.  And I think what's going wrong is that self.effect.texture2d0.enabled sets the state for everything that's drawn.

Answer (score 0):

self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = TRUE/FALSE does indeed set the state for everything in a preparetodraw block, so the solution was to use two preparetodraws.

First block:

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

```
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
[self.effect prepareToDraw];



glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);


glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nLiveSquares*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Followed by second block:

```
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = NO;
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _lineBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(LinePoint),(const GLvoid *) offsetof(LinePoint, Position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(LinePoint),(const GLvoid *) offsetof(LinePoint, Color));

// Set the line width
glLineWidth(50.0);

// Render the line

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);
```